# PhantomJS install while deploying Meteor application using mup deploy

Tags: node.js, meteor, phantomjs, meteor-up

Using mup deploy in mup.json file there is

```
// Install PhantomJS in the server
"setupPhantom": true,
```

I wonder if therefore I don't have to install PhantomJS separately by either adding PhantomJS package or load PhantomJS npm package and [spiderable](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/spiderable) package will work?

Comment: I think that's the point, yes, but I haven't checked.

Comment: Correct, you will not need phantom.js if you set that to true.

Comment: thanks, I just deployed and using www.example.com/?escaped_fragment_= produce rendering <body> code under view-source without any errors